# use customfield to filter with in marketo isnt working right

Tags: filter, marketo

im using marketo and the documentation says that you can [Filter](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/) with custom fields
but this isnt working

i hope some of you know why or how ??

what i know do is

```
XXX.mktorest.com/rest/v1/leads.json?filterType=lastName&filterValues=testlastname
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "lastName" field is part of the standard set of attributes for a lead in Marketo. Unfortunately, it is not one of the standard attributes that you can [query the Get Multiple Leads REST API as a filterType](http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-filter-type/).

The standard set of attributes to query the Get Multiple Leads REST API as a filterType are id, cookie, email, twitterId, facebookId, linkedInId, sfdcAccountId, sfdcContactId, sfdcLeadId, sfdcLeadOwnerId, and sfdcOpptyId.

You can query the Get Multiple Leads REST API for a custom field that you create in Marketo. A Marketo [custom field is a field extends the standard set of lead attributes](http://developers.marketo.com/blog/create-a-custom-field-in-marketo-and-update-this-field-via-api/).

Comment: when you get a lead with filterType is email - will the response contain your custom fields?  For some reason I am getting a response without the custom fields I've created.